# Moving a rectangle incredibly choppy

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I've created a simple program that draws a rectangle which falls down the screen at a constant rate. I first run Main.java:

```
package highst;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new GameFrame();
    }

}
```

which creates a new instance of GameFrame.java:

```
package highst;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public GameFrame() {
        super("Falling rectangle");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        GameLogic game = new GameLogic();
        this.getContentPane().add(game);
        this.setVisible(true);
        game.run();
    }
}
```

Which in turn creates a new instance of GameLogic.java:

```
package highst;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameLogic extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    Marvin marvin;
    private enum GameState{
        Running, Dead
    }

    GameState state = GameState.Running;

    public GameLogic(){
        marvin = new Marvin(50, 50);
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(marvin.getX(), marvin.getY(), 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            marvin.jump();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(state == GameState.Running){
            while(true){
                marvin.update();
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(17);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Which finally makes use of what will be my playable character, Marvin.java who is now a white rectangle:

```
package highst;

public class Marvin {

    private int x, y;

    public Marvin(int x, int y){
        this.x = y;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void update(){
        y -= -1;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void jump() {
        x += 1;
    }

}
```

It runs fine but the rectangle is not painted smoothly as it falls down the page. It seems to jump a few pixels at a time. I thought sleeping the thread for 17 milliseconds would cause everything to render smoothly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should implement some kind of doublebuffering to avoid flickering. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

Comment: Have you tried not sleeping at all?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Swing components are double buffered by default

Answer (score 1):

To have smooth animation, you need to make updates to the screen at a **constant rate**.

Here, you're doing a graphic repaint, which could take any amount of time, then waiting 17ms no matter what. This leads to each frame taking a different amount of time. The first frame might be done in 2ms, the next might take 5ms, then 3ms and so on... your frames will be displayed for 19ms then 22ms then 20ms...

What you need is a dedicated thread whose only job is to wait the right amount of time and then signal the main thread to repaint. Then your frames (provided they don't take more than 17ms to paint) come out every 17ms, exactly on cue.

[Here's an tutorial on animation in Java applets](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077117/client-side-java/animation-in-java-applets.html), you should find it relevant.

Comment: 1- I thought the OP already had a educated thread that waited the prescribed time. You're right in the fact that they're not taking into account the a amount of time it takes for a frame to be updated and repainted, but given that it's next to near impossible to know when the last frame was painted in Swing (and know which frame were talking about), the best you can hope for is knowing how long the update takes...

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1> Reducing the sleeping time of the thread to see the effects and get the optimum speed of falling.

2> Make use of Double Buffering (a concept in which the screen is painted first in memory and then painted onto the display monitor):

[Double Buffering - Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

[Double Buffering - Google Search Results](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=YtEMU-a_BqnO8gfMu4CQCg&gws_rd=cr#q=double+buffering)

3> Simple suggestion: Avoid using sleep(). Instead use Timers. It is a very interesting and powerful substitute for threads. Also it will not create problems in the later stages of your game development. Check these links out:

[Concurrency in java](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fessential%2Fconcurrency%2F&ei=ANIMU_fZE8eFrQfs2oCwAw&usg=AFQjCNF3FrgNWzrcD68bW3KKxkueP-Oryg&sig2=_RUFg6FA77v_JFtgMWOGhA&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bmk)

[Timer in Java](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FTimer.html&ei=JNIMU53gGoyErQe99oBQ&usg=AFQjCNGKrilkQ4yPxa15JXv8wuvVQIcrVg&sig2=c1YVP_KDsJ_IKIXiOuE6LA&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bmk)

4> Check out these interesting tutorials about animation in Java:

[Java World](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077117/client-side-java/animation-in-java-applets.html)

[Clear Rice](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/animation.html)

Comment: FYI, Swing components are double buffered by default

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I don't know. But during one project I was working on I had to use double buffering explicitly to resolve the problem of flickering and lag.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Maybe you are right. I need to research this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong...

1. You're ignoring the [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) of Swing and not starting your UI within the context of the EDT, which leads to...
2. You are calling `run` on the instance of `GameLogic` AND creating a `Thread` which will call `run` again, setting up to loops.  It's actually dumb luck that this worked at all.  What this does is calls `marvin.update` twice...and random intervals, meaning that the object is moved at inconsistent rates

Basically, you should remove the line `game.run()` and wrap `new GameFrame();` within the context of a `EventQueue.invokeLater` call...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            GameFrame frame = new GameFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

Personally, I'd recommend against extending from `JFrame` directly, you're not adding any functionality to the class, and simply create an instance within the `main` which you add your `GameLogic` panel to.  This makes the game infinitely more flexible in terms of deployment as you're not locking yourself into a single container.

I'd also encourage you not use `KeyListener`, but instead, make use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, as it solves the focus issues associated with `KeyListener`

Comment: I've implemented your change and removed `game.run()` but it's still choppy.

Comment: Really? How bizarre. I've a feeling it might be my laptop acting the fool. I've had nothing but bother trying to run things on it. Would you be able to upload your program somewhere so I can test it on my end?

Comment: Remember, Swing uses a passive renderng engine, so there's no guarantee that when you call repaint that a paint will actually occur, only that it a paint will occur at some time in the furpture